# How can I calculate number of transactions in one month using HERE SDK?

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

I'm using the Here android sdk and I'm trying to estimate the number of transactions by route. I'm just using the routing, the navigation and I have disabled the traffic.

Does anyone able to tell me how can I estimate the number of transactions please?

Answer (score 0):

A routing request of HERE SDK is same as HERE Routing API request, one request will be counted as one transaction. So you can count the number of request from SDK to estimate your usage.

However, please note If you enabled TrafficAvoidanceMode of HERE SDK Premium, SDK might calculate routes in the background from time to time, depends on your setting, for dynamic rerouting SDK will keep seeking for better route to avoid congestion, so the number of routing request will increase. If you want to have total control of number of request, please do not enable TrafficAvoidanceMode.

Ref: [Traffic-Aware Navigation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/dev_guide/topics/map-guidance-traffic-avoidance.html)

Also for HERE SDK Premium/Navigate, you can download offline map then perform offline routing request, it will also reduce the number of request.